# Is there a 10-digit emirp?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, decimal-expansion

Does a 10-digit emirp exist? Unfortunately, the lists of emirps I could find on the Web are quite small and my programming skills aren't good enough to write a program to check all the primes up to $10^{10}$.

Comment: Lots: $1025899211, 1025899307, 1025899411, 1025899531, 1025899579$, $1025899961, 1025900059, 1025900129, 1025900159, 1025900311, 1025900341$ are a few.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm a happy person now! :) Could you tell how you found them? What are the remaining ones?

Comment: Brute force. There are many more, the search is still running, so far about 10 million found.

Comment: @DanielFischer, say whaaat...

Comment: $33619380$ ten-digit emirps, so $16809690$ pairs, since there are no ten-digit prime palindromes.

Comment: @DanielFischer just wow! Can you share the list (if you can, please post it as an answer so people can upvote)?

Comment: Even compressed, the text file is 110 MB, too much for my measly connection, sorry.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks anyway for the info on how many there are. Also, it's funny to hear uploading 110 MB is a problem in 2014 :D

Comment: Well, I'm old, and so is my internet connection.

Comment: To avoid downloading, get a recent version of Pari/GP and do: `forprime(n=10^9,10^10,if(ispseudoprime(eval(concat(Vecrev(Str(n))))),print(n)))` or Perl: `use Math::Prime::Util qw/:all/; forprimes { say if is_prime(reverse $_) } 1e9,1e10;`  The latter takes about 2 minutes for the 33619380 emirps to be printed to wc on my machine.  I have to admit the GP digit reversal is googled black magic to me.

Comment: It doesn't matter for this range, but in general we should skip all the palindromes, hence Pari:  `forprime(n=1e9,1e10, r=eval(concat(Vecrev(Str(n)))); if (isprime(r) && r!=n,print(n)))`  or Perl:  `use Math::Prime::Util qw/:all/; forprimes { say if is_prime(reverse $_) && $_ ne reverse($_) } 1e9,1e10;`

Comment: @DanaJ thanks, I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Least 10-digit emirp is 1000000007.